# How to print un join lines using join command or awk?

Tags: join, awk

join command prints 2 common strings in 2 files. But is there any way to print the strings that did't match ?

file 1

```
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

file2

```
a  3
b  3
```

output

```
c  3
```

Comment: check here: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join on the first field, here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } !($1 in a)' file2 file1
```

Results:

```
c  3
```

Answer (score 5):

Using join command:

```
join -a1 -v1 file1 file2
```

`-a1` = print non-matching lines of first file. `-v` to suppress normal output

Comment: it says the following join: the -a and -v options are mutually exclusive

Comment: @user1883491: What is the output of `join --version | head -n 1`?